# Persisting information of a fragment from a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

A fragment has a text field whose information has to be persisted when the user scrolls from page to page. Saving the value of the text field to the model from TextWatcher.onTextChanged() is too early.

In which lifecycle method of the fragment would I need to persist the data to the model? I tried onSaveStateInstance() and onPause(). Neither of them gets called when the user scrolls from one page (fragment) to the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of just a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Then persist the information in each `Fragment`'s `onSaveInstanceState()` event.

Comment: Thanks kcoppock for your response. I am using FragmentPagerAdapter and have the persistence in onSaveInstanceState() - but onSaveInstanceState() is never being called.

Comment: kcoppock, I just realized that onSaveInstance() gets called after I scroll through two pages. So the first fragment's onSaveStateInstance() gets called after I have scrolled to the third page.